# Passing variable from Stack to BottomTab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

#### Current Behavior

When I navigate from home screen (stack navigator) to one of the pages, it passes the variable. However, when I click on a different page from the BottomTop navigator it does not pass the variable.

#### Expected Behavior

To pass variables from page to another when choosing them from the BottomTap navigator

#### Code

From HomeScreen (stack)

```
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen1", {loggedInUser: loggedInUser, Role: Role})}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

** I am getting loggedInUser and role from the login page

In Screen1 (bottomTab)

```
const { navigation } = this.props;  
const loggedInUser = navigation.getParam('loggedInUser');  
const Role = navigation.getParam('Role');
```

It gets these variable (loggedInUser & Role) on the first navigation from homepage to screen 1, but when I navigate from screen 1 to screen 2 (through BottomTab navigator) it doesn't pass the variables.

I read about AsyncStorage, keys & dangerouslyGetParent and didn't honestly know how to utilize them in my code.

#### Environment

| software         | version

| react-navigation |  4.0.10

| react-native     | 0.60.5

| node             | v10.16.0

| npm or yarn      | 6.12.0

Answer (score 0):

According to [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) passing parameters to routes only work with stack navigators. So you can't apply same scenario for tab navigators.

It is better to use Redux to save your data.